# android view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Добрый день.
Наткнулся на некоторую проблему при работе с viewPager.
На обоих вкладках отображается один и тот же фрагмент с тем же самым содержимым.
Т.е. содержимое не меняется в зависимости от страницы

Инициализация View Pager

```
  private void initializeUI() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPages; i ++){
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(pageTitle[i]));
    }
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    SympathyTakenPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SympathyTakenPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), numOfPages);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener(pager));
}

private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(ViewPager pager) {
    return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    };
}

public class SympathyTakenPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final int numOfTabs;

public SympathyTakenPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return SympathyTakenPageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numOfTabs;
}
}
```

Отображаемый фрагмент

```
public static SympathyTakenPageFragment newInstance(int pos) {
    SympathyTakenPageFragment fragment = new SympathyTakenPageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(SYMPATY_TYPE_KEY, pos);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    sympathyType = args.getInt(SYMPATY_TYPE_KEY);
    sympathyList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.e("SympathyTakenPage", "argument " +  sympathyType);
    emptySympathyTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    emptySympathyTV.setText("argument " +  sympathyType);
    //getServerData();
}
```

на обоих вкладках отображается "argument 2"

Comment: По коду не видно, как вы меняете содержимое во фрагменте в зависимости от страницы. Выложите полный код фрагмента.

Comment: @eugeneek думал вывода в лог будет достаточно, добавил TV. на обоих страницах в VP один  и тот же текст. Очень похоже, что VP инициализирует сразу 2 фрагмента, и первый перетирается и в итоге отображается только 2ой 2 раза, но не могу понять что не так в объявлении.

Comment: Похоже у вас проблемы с листнерами, которые дергают друг друга. Попробуйте убрать листнеры с `pager` и `tabLayout` и просто засетапить вью пейджер табам `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);`

Comment: @eugeneek не помогло

Comment: @eugeneek спасибо за помощь. И я не выложил достаточно кода для ее поиска. Как оказалось sympathyType оказался статичной.... и в общем все стало сразу ясно.